# Navigating via anchor tag causes empty ajax GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax

During navigation via links with anchor tag (#) an emty ajax GET request to the current page is generated

I have ajax dialogs which are shown by clicking  on links
But I cant understand why an empty ajax GET request is generated
[image]

Here is the javascript code which is binded to link

```
 $(document).on('click', '[data-js-click]', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).prop("tagName") != 'A') {
        var $self = $(this),
            $target = $($self.data('js-click') || 'a:first', $self);
        if ($target.length && typeof $target[0].click === "function") {
            var docId = $(this).find("input[name='Filter.DocIds']").val();
            window.location.hash = 'edit_docid=' + docId;
            $target[0].click();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Commenting the line "window.location.hash = 'edit_docid=' + docId;" code fixes the problem, but I need to add this hash tag

Comment: There's something weird... X-Requested-With is a header, it should not be in the query string. Also, it is very hard to help you on this matter without information about how the ajax requests are fired. I'm guessing that they're using a location change event?

Comment: @Salketer, I know it is very strange. I guess the same. Somethere in the code there is an event handler. But how this event handler can be called?

Comment: I have found the event handler  $(window).on('popstate', function (event) {       
        // To enable support for HTML5-History-API polyfill in your library        
        var location = window.history.location || window.location;
        var relativeUrl = location.pathname + location.search;
        var $link = $('a[data-ajax-history][href="' + relativeUrl + '"]');
        $link.trigger('click', true);
    });

Comment: this is certainly it... Is it from a library or soemthing? Post the code in an update to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

use custom data-href tag for #navigation and for the default href use javascript void.